# Why does the + sign in the Html will never works?

Tags: html

I am trying to create the rowspan and the colspan at the same time within the one tables. But, I think I will need to use my + sign and my scope html variables.
I believe the scope html variables is to force put down or to force put right hand side of your own tables.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <body>
        <table border= "1">
            
            <tr>
                <th>C1,R1,headings</th>
                <th>C2,R1,headings</th>
                <th>C3,R1,headings</th>
                <th>C4,R1,headings</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td rowspan= "2" + colspan="2">
                    stretching from C1,R2 into
                    the C2,R3
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td scope= "row" + scope= "col">
                    C3,R2,textAfterwards
                </td>
                <td scope= "row" + scope= "col">
                    C4,R2,textAfterwards
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td scope= "row" + scope= "col">
                    C3,R3,textAfterwards
                </td>
                <td scope= "row" + scope= "col">
                    C4,R3,textAfterwards
                </td>
            </tr>
            
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you do not use `+`.  you may want to start here: https://www.w3schools.com/Html/ or here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: Attributes on `html` elements are space separated `rowspan="1" colspan="2" style="..."`, etc etc.

Comment: "*I think I will need to use my + sign*" - what made you think this?

Comment: No, I have already said that I already need the rowspan and the colspan at the same time!!!!!

Comment: `<td rowspan="2" colspan="2">` That's all you need... No `+`...

Comment: No, I have already have tested it and it still looks like the same things and it does not still works.

Comment: You seem very confused about how table layouts work. For instance, the scope attribute doesn't do anything like what you think it does. Try explaining what layout of cells you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I think now I know why does the + sign will not works. I think it is something related to the sql tables that is not allowing us to have another + sign variables due to the server safety wise.

Answer (score 1):

You can have `rowspan` and `colspan` at the same time like this:

```
<td rowspan="2" colspan="2">
```

The confusion is that you seem to think they will be only applied if you use a + sign, but that's mistaken.